# Can I change default compiler used by cgo?

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to execute cgo code under ubuntu 14.04, it seems like cgo assume `CC/CXX` to be `gcc/g++`. And I need to explicitly specify `CC/CXX` in order to use, say, clang. Can I configure default compiler used through go's build constraints?

Thanks!

Comment: just a friendly reminder Cgo is not Go https://dave.cheney.net/2016/01/18/cgo-is-not-go https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo

Comment: @YandryPozo Appreciated, just experienced "Combing Go code and C code results in the intersection of both worlds, not the union; the memory safety of C, and the debuggability of a Go program." in past few days... although I love the first paragraph most :)

Answer (score 6):

The C or C++ compiler used by `cgo` can be specified using the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables respectively. For example, to use Clang:

```
CC=clang go build path/to/cgo/dependent/code.go
```

The variables can also specify flags to be passed to the compilers; for example, to run GCC with optimizations:

```
CC="gcc -O2" go build path/to/cgo/dependent/code.go
```

Answer (score 6):

You can specify which compiler to use by setting the `CC` environment variable:

`go env -w "CC=clang"`

Comment: This is actually a good answer