# Golang & CGO – link to a DLL dynamic library

Tags: go, dll, clang, cgo, cc

Go language positions itself as a **cross-platform** language. To me a cross-platform language is that kind of language which is usable on all the supported platforms.

I would like to use its ability to link to a DLL dynamic library. DLL libraries are used on Windows operating systems, and Golang is known to support Windows O.S.

Golang's GitHub repository does not allow me to post questions there, they redirect me to StackOverflow (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Questions), so let it be so.

The library was written in `C` language. Golang is known to support the `C` language using the so called "CGO" feature.

I know about the `syscall` package. I would like to use the "**CGO**" feature on purpose.

I know that Golang provides a method to specify a `C` compiler for CGO using the `CC` variable. I want to know what is the proper way to use `CLang` compiler (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) in Go's CGO for my purpose.

So, my questions to the creators and maintainers of the Go language are following.

1. How do I link to a `C` language DLL in Go ?
2. How do I use `CLang` compiler for CGO ?
3. How do I see the output (`stdout` for `C` people) of the compilation and linkage process in CGO ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

```
 go env -w CC="D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe"
```

sets the C compiler.

```
go env CC
D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe
```

but when I try to compile something it says:

```
... build constraints exclude all Go files in ...
```

I fix this by setting environment variable `CGO_ENABLED` to `1` in my IDE.

Then a new error jumps out:

```
cgo: C compiler "D:\\Program" not found: exec: "D:\\Program": file does not exist
```

Looks like Go is still not supporting spaces in CC ?!

**cmd/go: CC variable misparsed when set to a path containing spaces #41400**
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41400

> @gopherbot gopherbot closed this as completed in 742dcba on Aug 16, 2021.

```
go version
go version go1.20.3 windows/amd64
```

I use the native go tool to add double quotes to my CC variable:

```
go env -w CC="\"D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe\""
go env CC
"D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe"
```

Alternative way will be to use native Windows tool to set the variable manually.

```
SET CC="D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe"

ECHO %CC%
"D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe"

go env CC
"D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe"
```

Looks like success ? Not yet.

```
go build .
# test/sdl-wrapper
D:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe failed: exit status 1104
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-tsaware'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-nxcompat'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-major-os-version=6'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-minor-os-version=1'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-major-subsystem-version=6'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-minor-subsystem-version=1'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-dynamicbase'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-high-entropy-va'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/T'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-start-group'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-end-group'; ignored
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL2.lib'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1104 (use -v to see invocation)
```

OK. I add `SDL2.lib` and `SDL2.dll` to the current folder.

```
go build .
# test/sdl-wrapper
D:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running D:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe failed: exit status 1104
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-tsaware'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-nxcompat'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-major-os-version=6'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-minor-os-version=1'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-major-subsystem-version=6'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-minor-subsystem-version=1'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-dynamicbase'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-high-entropy-va'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/T'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-start-group'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-end-group'; ignored
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mingwex.lib'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1104 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I do not see any signs of `mingwex.lib` in the source codes of SDL2 library.
My code is not using this file also.
What does this error mean then ?

**build: cgo with clang and -buildmode=c-shared failures on Windows #42146**
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42146

I saw some people making merge requests to the Golang's source code to fix this mistake. But these attempts are being blocked by Google.
https://github.com/golang/go/pull/54811

Wikipedia says that

> LLVM currently supports compiling of Ada, C, C++, D, Delphi, Fortran, Haskell, Julia, Objective-C, Rust, and Swift using various front ends. Widespread interest in LLVM has led to several efforts to develop new front ends for a variety of languages.

Wikipedia also notes that CLang is primarily supported by Apple.

I guess now I know why Google is stopping all the attempts to make the language really cross-platform. But ... this is not smart at all.

Either they support LLVM sooner or later, or they will lose this war of formats.

**Let's try to dig this thing out and see what it is**

It looks like the only usage of `mingwex` text in Golang's source code comes from the `src/cmd/link/internal/ld/lib.go` file. This file has a super intersting comment in its top:

```
// Inferno utils/8l/asm.c
// https://bitbucket.org/inferno-os/inferno-os/src/master/utils/8l/asm.c
//
//  Copyright © 1994-1999 Lucent Technologies Inc.  All rights reserved.
//  Portions Copyright © 1995-1997 C H Forsyth (forsyth@terzarima.net)
//  Portions Copyright © 1997-1999 Vita Nuova Limited
//  Portions Copyright © 2000-2007 Vita Nuova Holdings Limited (www.vitanuova.com)
//  Portions Copyright © 2004,2006 Bruce Ellis
//  Portions Copyright © 2005-2007 C H Forsyth (forsyth@terzarima.net)
//  Revisions Copyright © 2000-2007 Lucent Technologies Inc. and others
//  Portions Copyright © 2009 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
```

OK, here we see that this piece of software is provided as is and we can do whatever we want to do with it. Let it be so.

I am searching for a hard-coded name of a GCC library used on Linux O.S. in a cross-platform language Golang, which should be working on Windows O.S. Let's check this thing out.

First of all, my eye sticks to the following moment. The `mingwex` is not used in constants like in common sense programming practice, but it is **hard-coded** and **scattered** across different parts of the `lib.go` file. This shows the level of quality very distinctly. Let's count the usages.

The first usage is on line 683 in function `func loadWindowsHostArchives(ctxt *Link) {` :

```go
if p := ctxt.findLibPath("libmingwex.a"); p != "none" { ... }
```

The second usage is in the same function on line 729 and it is commented in a `TODO` block.

The third usage is in the function `func (ctxt *Link) hostlink() {` which starts on line 1342 and ends on line 1902.

Here I must stop and make another comment. Well, usage of gigantic functions ~1000 lines long is also a sign of a bad quality. If you want to make a good product – you should read how code is written in C++ language for example. It is just a piece of advice. C++ is concidered to be the most difficult programming language in the world by many programmers and their standards are more than just words ...

In this gigantic function which is unreadable in practice, `mingwex` is used on line 1789:

```go
argv = append(argv, "-Wl,--start-group", "-lmingwex", "-lmingw32", "-Wl,--end-group")
```

Apart from these three places, the `mingwex` is not used in the source code of Golang 1.20.3.

Comment: I don’t think you are setting the environment variable correctly for windows. That error is from your shell (PowerShell I think), not from go. You can use [`go env`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Environment_variables) command to set specific go environment variables too if you’re not sure how to do it on windows

Comment: You linked to the duplicate, so it was changed more recently than that, but still in current releases. Are you using go1.20?

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.20.3 version of Golang.

Comment: Regarding the issues with the spaces, use quotes. https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/334732/

Comment: This has nothing to do with clang being commonly used on macOS (clang is used in lots of places), or Go's cross-platform compatibility (this is related to user configured compilers and linkers outside of Go's control). CGO was a tool first written to work with gcc, that's all. The fact that there might be bugs on a less common platform is not "Google stopping all attempts..." - get over the grand conspiracy theories, and there is no "war of formats" whatever that means. if you supplied the correct ldflags for your library and it doesn't work, then it might be a bug, which can be fixed.

Comment: Well, if it is not a conspiracy, then I hope they will fix this in future versions of Golang.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using cgo ldflags you can add link flags to link with the library, e.g.

   ```
   // #cgo LDFLAGS: -lpng
   import "C"
   ```
2. Using the `CC` environment variable, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013491/362589).
3. It is just in the standard output of go build.

Comment: 2. In that question it is not specified which format is used in value of CC. Is it an absolute path to the compiler's executable file or a relative path ? If relative, which folder is used as a base ?

Comment: @Pikachu: it seems like an absolute path (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38372#issuecomment-612307055)

Comment: Looks like simple usage of the `CC` variable does not solve the question. Check the updated question mentioning the error: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1104 (use -v to see invocation)`.